# How do I remove a substring after a certain character in a string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, substring

How do I remove a substring after a certain character in a string using Ruby?

Comment: Well I believe the title is self-explanatory enough. Also, I accepted Jacob's answer about 13 hours ago, just give others some time; normally people don't keep refreshing the same page and waiting for answers.

Comment: Editing the title isn't to benefit you. It's to benefit others who are looking for an answer to the same problem. No clarifying your title and question actually hurts you because no one will upvote your question if they think its useless. Just my two cents.

Comment: The question doesn't explain how long the substring is, so it is really vague.  Apparently you wanted the substring to start immediately after the first instance of a certain character extend all the way to end of the main string.  Don't expect us to read minds.  Another telepath might ask the same question as you but demand a different answer because she only wants to remove a substring of length 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate (with arguably better answers): [Remove "@" sign and everything after it in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001625/remove-sign-and-everything-after-it-in-ruby)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
new_str = str.slice(0..(str.index('blah')))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to get to the end of the delimeter: `new_str = str.slice(0..(str.index('blah') + 'blah'.length))`

Comment: what happens if the given character is not found in the string ?

Comment: if character is not found - then it will throw an exception ArgumentError: bad value for range

Answer (score 34):

I find that `"Part1?Part2".split('?')[0]` is easier to read.

Comment: but then you'd have to add back in the ? if you wanted it, so I don't think answers your exact question.

Comment: I like this answer, because you don't have to check whether "?" is present, it also works with any other string withouth throwing an exception.

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised nobody suggested to use 'gsub'

```
irb> "truncate".gsub(/a.*/, 'a')
=> "trunca"
```

The bang version of gsub can be used to modify the string.

Comment: Don't you mean `/(?<=a).*/` or `/a\K.*/`, to exclude `"a"` from the match?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah right, that or re-introduce the char. Nice catch.

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "Hello World"
stopchar = 'W'
str.sub /#{stopchar}.+/, stopchar
#=> "Hello W"
```

Answer (score 5):

A special case is if you have multiple occurrences of the same character and you want to delete from the last occurrence to the end (not the first one).
Following what Jacob suggested, you just have to use `rindex` instead of `index` as `rindex` gets the index of the character in the string but starting from the end.
Something like this:

```
str = '/path/to/some_file'
puts str.slice(0, str.index('/')) # => ""
puts str.slice(0, str.rindex('/')) # => "/path/to"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `partition` and `rpartition`depending on whether we want to use the first or last instance of the specified character:

```
string = "abc-123-xyz"
last_char = "-"

string.partition(last_char)[0..1].join   #=> "abc-"
string.rpartition(last_char)[0..1].join   #=> "abc-123-"
```