# Rspec Array match partial string timestamp

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, assert

I have a array like this:

```
["xxxxxxxxx", 448, "2016-08-29", 1, "Trading", 53, "Trading", 2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500, 2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500, "RBS", "USD", "United States Dollar", nil, 2016-10-08 00:00:00 -0500, 2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500, "2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500","lcz076", nil, 5, 2016-10-08 00:00:00 -0500, 2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500, "9", 448, "P", nil]
```

And I need to match a value for this value only `"2016-09-08 00:00:00"`

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you just want to check if it is inside? then use `.include?`

Answer (score 0):

First convert all the dates into `Strings`

Then after set it to a variable `a`

`a = ["xxxxxxxxx", 448, "2016-08-29", 1, "Trading", 53, "Trading", "2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500, 2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500"...`

I noticed all of the dates of the type you wanted to check have `-0500` so you can take out that part by looping in the array with this

`new_str[i] = str.slice(0..(str.index('-0500')))`

Now you can just use `.include?("stuff here")`

Comment: Its always Last 5 digits so how do you slice that last 5 instead

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486709/how-do-i-remove-substring-after-a-certain-character-in-a-string-using-ruby, you will learn alot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
a = ["xxxxxxxxx", 448, "2016-08-29", 1, "Trading", 53, "Trading", "2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500", "2016-06-03 00:00:00 -0500", "RBS", "USD", "United States Dollar", nil, "2016-10-08 00:00:00 -0500", "2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500", "2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500", "lcz076", nil, 5, "2016-10-08 00:00:00 -0500", "2016-09-08 00:00:00 -0500", "9", 448, "P", nil]
```

RSpec expectation should be:

```
matches = a.select{ |x| x.to_s.match("2016-09-08 00:00:00") }
expect(matches).not_to be_empty
```