# How to remove a certain character after substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string with exclamation marks. I want to remove the exclamation marks at the end of the word, not the ones before a word. Assume there is no exclamation mark by itself/ not accompanied by a word. By word I mean [a..z], can be uppercased.

For example:

```
exclamation("Hello world!!!")
#=> ("Hello world")

exclamation("!!Hello !world!")
#=> ("!!Hello !world")
```

I have read [How do I remove substring after a certain character in a string using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486709/how-do-i-remove-substring-after-a-certain-character-in-a-string-using-ruby) ; these two are close, but different.

```
def exclamation(s)
  s.slice(0..(s.index(/\w/)))
end

# exclamation("Hola!") returns "Hol"
```

I have also tried `s.gsub(/\w!+/, '')`. Although it retains the `'!'` before word, it removes *both* the last letter and exclamation mark. `exclamation("!Hola!!") #=> "!Hol"`.

How can I remove only the exclamation marks at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex that sometimes difficult to understand use this:

```
def exclamation(sentence)
  words = sentence.split
  words_wo_exclams = words.map do |word|
    word.split('').reverse.drop_while { |c| c == '!' }.reverse.join
  end
  words_wo_exclams.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't given a lot of test data, here's an example of something that might work:

```
def exclamation(string)
  string.gsub(/(\w+)\!(?=\s|\z)/, '\1')
end
```

The `\s|\z` part means either a space or the end of the string, and `(?=...)` means to just peek ahead in the string but not actually match against it.

Note that this won't work in the case of things like `"I'm mad!"` where the exclamation mark is not adjacent to a space, but you could always add that as another potential end-of-word match.

Answer (score 1):

```
"!!Hello !world!, world!! I say".gsub(r, '')
  #=> "!!Hello !world, world! I say"
```

where

```
r = /
    (?<=[[:alpha:]])  # match an uppercase or lowercase letter in a positive lookbehind
    !                 # match an exclamation mark
    /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

or

```
r = /
    [[:alpha:]]       # match an uppercase or lowercase letter
    \K                # discard match so far
    !                 # match an exclamation mark
    /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

If the above example should return `"!!Hello !world, world I say"`, change `!` to `!+` in the regexes.